# Asociar datos de un formulario a un usuario Llave Foránea

Tags: python, django

Estoy trabajando en una aplicación web para crear publicaciones

este es mi model para las publicaciones

```
class Post(models.Model):
title = models.CharField(max_length=50)
content = models.CharField(max_length=1000)
image = models.ImageField(upload_to='user', null=True, blank=True)
user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

def __str__(self):
    return "%s %s %s %s" % (self.title, self.content, self.image, self.user.username)
```

Quiero que cuando el usuario se cree una publicacion, dicha publicacion se le asocie a ese usuario que la creo

estas son mis views:

```
lass AddNewPost(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
model = Post
form_class = FormNewPost
template_name = 'new_post.html'

def get(self, request):
    data = {"forms": self.form_class()
            }
    return render(request, self.template_name, data)

def post(self, request):
    user = request.user.pk
    form = self.form_class(request.POST, request.FILES)
    if form.is_valid():
        form.save()
```

con la variable usuarios obtengo el usuario que tiene la sesión activa pero mi duda es como asocio esa publicación al usuario creado?

Añado mi form por si es necesario:

```
class FormNewPost(forms.ModelForm):
class Meta:
    model = Post
    fields = 'title', 'content', 'image',
    labels = {
        'title': 'Titulo de la publicación',
        'content': 'Contenido de la publicación',
        'image': 'Agrega una imagen'
    }

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(FormNewPost, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['title'].widget.attrs.update({'placeholder': 'Ingresa el titulo de tu publicación a crear'})
    self.fields['content'].widget = forms.Textarea(attrs={
        'class': 'input100',
        'placeholder': 'Ingresa contenido educativo'
    })

    for field in self.fields:
        self.fields[field].widget.attrs.update({'class': 'input100'} )
```

Answer (score 1):

Puede intentar con el siguiete código en la vista

```py
class AddNewPost(LoginRequiredMixin, View):
model = Post
form_class = FormNewPost
template_name = 'new_post.html'
# Ruta del login
login_url = '/accounts/login/'
redirect_field_name = 'next'

def form_valid(self, form):
    # Otenemos el formulario y con (commit=false) no lo guardamos en la base de datos
    save_it = form.save(commit=false)
    # Obtenemos el usuario con la sesión activa y lo asignamos al post
    save_it.user = self.request.user
    # Guardamos el formulario
    save_it.save()
    #Retornamos al inico
    return redirect('/')
```

Información sobre [LoginRequiredMixin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/auth/default/).